# Codeigniter url rewrite like subdomain url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Currently my Url is: http://www.domain.co.uk/index.php/city/details/city-name

I would like to change it to:

http://www.city-name.domain.co.uk/index.php/city/details/city-name

or:

http://www.city-name.domain.co.uk/city/details/city-name

Answer (score 1):

Put the .htaccess file into the http ://www.domain.co.uk/ document root

To http ://www.city-name.domain.co.uk/index.php/city/details/city-name

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ http://www.$2.domain.co.uk/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

To http ://www.city-name.domain.co.uk/index.php/city/details/city-name

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/([^/]+)$ http://www.$2.domain.co.uk/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

If the server is the same, set above RewriteRule this line to prevent redirection loop

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*).domain\.co\.uk [NC]
```

File content example

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*).domain\.co\.uk [NC]  
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/([^/]+)$ http://www.$2.domain.co.uk/$1/$2 [R=301,L]  
</IfModule>
```

To exclude domain.co.uk (whitout www)

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*).domain\.co\.uk [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co\.uk [NC]  
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/([^/]+)$ http://www.$2.domain.co.uk/$1/$2 [R=301,L]     
</IfModule>
```

Comment: but one more problem is there. now CSS and image paths is not working

Comment: please, could you put a example of css and image path?

Comment: there is problem. the code u said is not working. there is subdomain with same name that worked when did rewrite..so i just wanna replace url no need to redirect. ur code is redirecting http://www.domain.co.uk/index.php/city/details/city-name to http://www.city-name.domain.co.uk Can u give me a code that is  url replacing code??