# how to add subdomain name from current url using .htacces rules

Tags: url

I have a URL link like,
  [http://domain.com/abs/def/city](http://domain.com/abd/def/city) and,

i want to display it as  [http://city.domain.com/ABC/def](http://city.domain.com/abc/def)

using .htaccess.

Can any one help me by providing .ht access rules.

I want to write .htaccess rules for each city name in URL act as sub domain name.
Also i want it to be dynamic as there are different cities are available in site.

i am using below code in .htaccess file, but not working properly.

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]+)$ http://$3.domain/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

is there any way to get my requirement using or by modifying my above code or by some other .htaccess code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what you ask is not possible. This is a typical missunderstanding about url rewriting:

Url rewriting rewrites (manipulates) *incoming* requests on the server side before processing them. It is *not* possible to alter *outgoing* content such that contained urls are changed by this means.

There are solutions for that though:

- apaches proxy module can "map" one url into the scope of some other url
- there are also modules for automatic post processing of generated html markup
- more exotic or creative solutions exist, it depends on your situation in the end...

But usually the easiest is to change the application (typically just its central configuration) such that it contains final urls (pointing to the subdomain in your case). Then you can indeed use the rewriting module to "re-map" those to the previous scope when future incoming requests refer to them (they got clicked).

---

Ok, second step getting additional info from your comments:

Just to get this clear: you understand that it is not possible to change the link you send out by means of rewriting, but you want to change the url shown in the browser *after* the user has clicked on some city link? *That* is something different to what you wrote before, that actually is possible. Great.

If the rewriting works as you want it to (you see the desired url in the browsers address bar), then we can go on. The error message indicates a name resolution problem, that has nothing to do with rewriting. Most likely the domain "cambridge.192.168.2.107" cannot be resolved, which is actually not surprising. You cannot mix ip addresses and names, it is either or.

Also I see that you are using internal, non-routable addresses. So you also are responsible for the name resolution yourself, since no public DNS server can guess what you are setting up internally. Did you do that?

I suggest these steps:

1. stop using an ip addres for this, use a domain name.
2. since you are working internally, take care that that domain name is actually resolved to your local systems ip address. How you do this depends on your setup and system, obviously. Most likely you need some entry in the file `/etc/hosts` or similar.
3. you need to take care that also those "subdomain names" get resolved to the same address. This is not trivial, again it depends on the setting and system you locally use.
4. if that name resolution works, then you should see a request in your http servers access log file. Then and only then it makes sense to go on...

Comment: is there any .htaccess code that can be help to get my goal.like i am using below .htaccess code but not working properly as it redirect as "page not found!"
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.)/(.)/([^/]+)$ http://$3.domain/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer that since I have no details about the situation. What url is requested and what is it rewritten to? _you_ know that, not me. A hint: as ALWAYS when trying to setup or debug rewriting rules: ENABLE REWRITE LOGGING! Check the excellent documentation of the rewriting module, you will find the commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` in there. They help you to understand _exactly_ what is actually going on inside the rewriting engine for each request. Don't try to _guess_ what happens, switch on the lights (logging) and take a close look!

Comment: ok, see i have site having product listing by city name.so there is list of city and each city name having link like http://domain/state/city. on that page there is a list of product having this city. but i want to re-write my url as : http://city.domain/state.
i use this link as reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558384/codeigniter-url-rewrite-like-subdomain-url-with-htaccess
so instead of URL http://domain/state/city , i want to be http://city.domain/state

Comment: I did understand that. But as written: this is not possible by means of rewriting. The rewriting module simply cannot alter the links you send out. If you send html markup containing like like `domain.com/state/city` then these links go out like that. The rewriting module cannot be used to alter them. It can only alter _incoming_ requests.

Comment: i fallow the below link code which match my requiremnt but not working properly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558384/codeigniter-url-rewrite-like-subdomain-url-with-htaccess

can you help me by find out is there any mistack to use that code in my site.

Comment: Sorry, it appears you don't really read or understand what I reply. I asked several things, you don't react to that. You repeat what you are wrote before without really adding details. Sorry.

Comment: ok, here is my link containing the city list:http://192.168.2.107/state/EE and by click on any city name i want url display like:http://cambridge.192.168.2.107/b/city/552/Cambridge , instead of url http://192.168.2.107/b/city/552/Cambridge

i am using below code, that change the url dynamically but gives erro as "server not found".

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]+)$ http://$4.192.168.2.107/$1/$2/$3/$4 [R=301,L]  
</IfModule>

Comment: I added a "second step" to the answer above with some suggestions. If you have more questions it would make sense to continue this exchange in a place better suited for interactive discussions. Since you do not have enough reputation points (yet!) to use the internal chat: do you have access to IRC chat? Then contact me on freenode irc, same nick name as here. Usually you can find me in channels #kde or #owncloud.